# To be + past participle in English

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, infinitives

I have one doubt about the structure “to be + past participle”

In some cases I have seen ‘to be + past participle’ replaces ‘is to be + past participle’

Example:

> this work is to be done ⤏ this work to be done.

My question is, does ‘to be + past participle’  replaces ‘was to be + past participle’ also?

Like example:

> this work to be done ⤏ this work was to be done.

in any of the cases can we use like that?

Comment: *The work (to be done)* is a different grammatical structure from *the work **is** (to be done)*.  The first is not a complete sentence.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. What does *verb3* mean? This is not a standard abbreviation. Also, as per Andrew's comment, the two phrases in each example are not equivalent : one is a sentence, the other is a phrase.

Comment: Yeah, what is a verb3, anyway.

Comment: @Lambie I took the liberty to change "verb 3" to "past participle". Perhaps, OP's intention was the third form of the verb. Or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Active voice : present perfect> To have sent.
Passive voice : present perfect> To have been sent .

Form                   Active voice                    Passive voice
Simple Present         To sent                         To be sent.
Simple Present Cont     To be sending                  -